# Prove the continuity of function in 0

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

About function  $ f:  R \rightarrow R $ we know that it holds equality 
$f(x) + \sin(f(x)) = x $ for all  $x \in R$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

First: I can see that in $0$ we have: $f(0) + \sin(f(0)) = 0 $ so it is complied only when $f(0)$ is equal $0$.

Second: I use Heine definition of continuity of function. So I take any sequence $x_{n}$ convergent to $0$, and I prove that $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow 0$.

so we had $f(x_{n}) + \sin(f(x_{n})) = x_{n}$.

so after passing to the border $x_{n} \rightarrow 0$  we had that:

$f(x_{n}) + \sin(f(x_{n})) \to 0 $ so it is complied only when $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ so it prove I think continuity this function in $0$.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not continuous at $0$, that means $f(0+)\neq f(0-)$. But we have both $f(0+)$ and $f(0-)$ are solutions to the equation $x+\sin x=0$. Not that $g(x):=x+\sin x$ is nondecreasing. So $x+\sin x=0$ admits only one solution, that is $0$. Thus, we must have $f(0+)=f(0-)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to prove: $$f(x_n)+\sin\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)\to 0\iff x_n\to 0.$$

Observe that $$g(u)=u+\sin u$$ is an increasing function. This should help.

Comment: $f(x_{n})+sin(f(x_{n}))→0⟺f(x_{n})→0.$ I think it should be. Yes I now it is incresing function I can prove it, but I am not sure how exactly prove it in correct form when I pass to border with it..... I' ve hope you understand my doubts...

Comment: Try to apply continuity of the inverse function. Our $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and increasing, so the inverse function is continuous. In particular...